# Choose 1 event in Angular6 "or"

Tags: angular

I want send my form when the user press enter o my input lost focus, but only 1 time, because if I do enter and then I change focus, my event is execute 2 times (1 for enter,2 for change focus).

```
  <form class="form-custom" #m="ngForm">
          <div class="form-custom--input-btn">
            <input #ofi="ngModel" type="text" class="clr-col-12 form-custom--input form-custom--input"
              id="oficina" (keyup.enter)="hello()" (focusout)="hello()" name="oficina" [(ngModel)]="oficina" minlength="4" maxlength="4" [placeholder]="placeholderOficina" required>
            <button type="button"  class="btn--custom-over-input btn--custom-over-input--arrow" [disabled]="mult.invalid" (click)="hello()"></button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I have in my input -> `(keyup.enter)="hello()" (focusout)="hello()"` 
And in my button (click)="hello()">

I need that Angular only get 1 event or `(keyup.enter)="hello()" (focusout)="hello()"`

Answer (score 0):

To start with, its always a good idea to call submit in a form, i.e.

```
<form (submit)="doSomething()">
```

so the user can actually hit Enter and the form gets submitted.

Secondly, you can introduce a local variable like formSubmitted (which is true or false), which is checked in your hello method like so:

```
hello() {
  if (formSubmitted) {
    return;
  }
  // doWhatEverYouNeedtoHere
}
```